# ¿Como insertar un valor a una base de datos en sql con lenguaje python?

Tags: python, sql

```
from query import PzasOP14

ns = event.source.parent.getComponent('NoDeSerie').text
pok= event.source.parent.getComponent('PzaOk').text
pnk= event.source.parent.getComponent('PzaOk').text
tc = event.source.parent.getComponent('TiempoCiclo').text
cb = event.source.parent.getComponent('CodigoDeBarras').text
mdl= event.source.parent.getComponent('Modelo').text
trn= event.source.parent.getComponent('Turno').text


query = " INSERT INTO [dbo].[PzasOp14] (NoDeSerie, PzaOk, PzaNok, TiempoCiclo, CodigoDeBarras, Modelo, Turno) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
args = [006,1,0,200,1365411,541,654]
system.db.runPrepUpdate(query,args)
```

Tengo una tabla donde insertar los datos de numero de serie, tiempo de ciclo y codigo de barras pero al hacer el script en python no inserta nada y los me aparecer:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named query

Comment: No publiques dos veces la misma pregunta. [esta es tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/209640/78).

Answer (score 0):

En la primera línea de tu script, haces un import:

```
from query import PzasOP14
```

Para que esto funcione, debe existir el módulo `query.py`, que a su vez, debe declarar la función `PzasOP14`

El mensaje de error indica que el sistema es incapaz de encontrar el archivo `query.py`, requerido por tu script.

La búsqueda se realiza entre los módulos por defecto de phyton, y en las carpetas definidas en la variable `sys.path`. Quizás el fallo esté en que esta variable no está bien inicializada.

Más información en la documentación de [*modules*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) (en inglés).